# D&D 5th edition questions

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, saving-throw

A group of friends and myself are starting up D&D for the first time. So we are starting with the 5th edition since it's the latest edition. Now I am currently building my character and I am having trouble with finding out stats for some things. I am going to be a Dragonborn (Silver) Cleric. How do you determine saving throws, skills, inspiration, and proficiency bonus. Passive Wisdom? What is that?

[image: Saving Throws/Skills]

[image: Passive wisdom perception]

Comment: Voting to Close because this is all covered pretty explicitly in the free and easily downloadable D&D basic.

Comment: This is an overly broad question.  It would take far to much space here to explain all that you are asking about.  Take a look at our [tour] and go through the [help] for general guidelines on asking questions here.  Welcome to the RPG Stack Exchange.

Comment: Here is a link to WOTC's page to download the basic rules http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules?x=dnd/basicrules

Comment: Hi and welcome, it would be very helpful for you to read over the relevant sections of the rules *very carefully* and ask a *specific* question about concepts you're having trouble with. We know that reading an RPG manual is a learned skill and are happy to help, but we need something more specific, we can't explain the whole game.

Comment: I don't mean to sound stupid, but I've read through the book, and I don't see it clearly stated. It stated some facts about it, but nothing was cut and dry clear. I thank you all for taking the time to reply even if it was downvotes or what gomad says is snippy comments. I'm okay with it, I'm new to D&D and I'm just trying to get information as clear as possible which Mag Roader did for me

Comment: @Norixius If you've done your research and still don't understand what's going on, you should say so. If there's specific points of confusion (e.g. "I don't see where any of this is explained") that's useful to state. I don't think anyone was really trying to be snippy; we _are_ friendly and I'm baffled by gomad feeling he needed to say that as if we were being otherwise.

Comment: @NorixiusTokris Hopefully you'll find that we are quite patient! We love new folks, we just have pretty exacting standards for questions (and we acknowledge that there is a quite the learning curve here, both for D&D and using this site). Our aim is to help you the best we can as specifically as possible. The big thing is that we really want the specific details. What *specifically* are you having trouble understanding with the concept. For instance on the saving throws ask "I'm seeing this thing called passive wisdom, I know this is what the rule say [quote] what does this mean exactly?"

Comment: Currently i don't understand all the terms. I'm trying to learn them, and I have been researching with google trying to find explanations. I've read into the 5e book, and I get some of the stuff. Like. Where do you find the skills modifier number to start out at for 1st levelers. I want to be as knowledgeable as I can, because I'm the one hosting (but not being DM) so I want to pretty much all there is to know. If you can provide links, or something for me to read up on and what not or page numbers to read in. It would mean a ton. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @NorixiusTokris once you get the rep Id suggest joining Chat if you have a bunch of rules comprehension problems at once, especially as a brand new RPG player. While 5e is meant for newbies to the hobby, it still has a lot of baggage and expectations and we'd love to help. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are a Dragonborn, you are using the Player's HandBook (PHB).  Nearly every one of your questions is clearly explained in various parts of the character creation process, so please read through that. However, I'll give you a broad overview of what those things on the character sheet do to hopefully point you in the right direction.

Inspiration is granted by the DM for playing well, so it's not part of character creation. It lets you take advantage on 1 saving throw / Attack roll / ability check of your choice.

Proficiency bonus starts at +2 and goes up slowly as you level; the bonus is shown in the leveling table for any class. The bonus applies to any ability check / Attack roll / saving throw for which you are proficient in the associated skill or tool / weapon / saving throw ability.

Proficiencies in skills / saving throws / tools / weapons come from your class, race, and background. Some are chosen by you from a selection the rules provide, while others are granted explicitly by the rules. The little dots on the sheet are to indicate proficiency.

Every ability score has a modifier associated with it - for example, 10 grants a +0 bonus while 12 grants a +1 bonus (and the pattern continues with more/less bonus for every even score). Rolling an ability check often comes attached to a skill, in which case the bonus you add to your d20 roll is your ability modifier + proficiency bonus (assuming you are proficient). For example, a Dexterity (Stealth) check if you have Dex 14 and proficiency in Stealth would be rolled with a +4 bonus (+2 for 14, +2 for 1st level proficiency).

Passive Wisdom (Perception) is 10 + your Perception, which is Wisdom Bonus + proficiency bonus (assuming you are proficient in Perception).